# Compiling in texmaker wih bibtex without citations

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, miktex

I am a recent user of Texmaker and I have a strange problem when compiling a tex file which does not include citations or bibliography.

When compiling, I receive the message:
"This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit) The top-level auxiliary file: toto.aux I found no \citation commands---while reading file toto.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file toto.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file toto.aux (There were 3 error messages)"

This is the usual message you receive when you make no citations in your tex file. But here I am not including any bibliography line so I am not sure where the problem comes from.

I guess there is an option I should deactivate in the parameters, but I couldn't figure which one.

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: Use a profile setting without BibTeX call.